# Compiling ISO SQL-2003 ANTLR Grammar

Tags: java, sql, parsing, antlr

I am trying to compile the ISO-SQL 2003 grammar from here 
http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/1304304798093/SQL2003_Grammar.zip. All three versions of it can be found here http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/list.html.

These are the steps I followed,

1. java -jar antlr-3.3-complete.jar -Xmx8G -Xwatchconversion sql2003Lexer.g
2. java -jar antlr-3.3-complete.jar -Xmx8G -Xwatchconversion sql2003Parser.g
3. javac ANTLRDemo.java

ANTLRDemo.java file:

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class ANTLRDemo {
   static String readFile(String path) throws IOException 
   {
       byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
       return new String(encoded, "UTF-8");
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       ANTLRStringStream in = new ANTLRStringStream( readFile(args[0]) );
       sql2003Lexer lexer = new sql2003Lexer(in);
       CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
       sql2003Parser parser = new sql2003Parser(tokens);
       parser.eval();
   }
}
```

First two steps work fine, then while compiling my main class I get a lot of errors related to Java syntax like these:

> ./sql2003Parser.java:96985: error: not a statement
>                 $UnsignedInteger.text == '1'
>   ./sql2003Parser.java:96985: error: ';' expected
>                 $UnsignedInteger.text == '1'
>   ./sql2003Parser.java:102659: error: unclosed character literal
>               if ( !(((Unsigned_Integer3887!=null?Unsigned_Integer3887.getText():null) == '01')) ) {

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong in setting up the parser.
 It would be helpful if someone can show me how exactly to setup this grammar using ANTLR.

Edit: After a little more fiddling, I think that these errors are caused by the actions present in lexer and parser rules. Is there a safe way to overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything wrong, ANTLR has never been able to generate a working Java parser from these grammar files.

According to a post by Douglas Godfrey to [antlr-interest in Oct 2011](http://www.antlr3.org/pipermail/antlr-interest/2011-October/042862.html):

> I generated a C parser and lexer. they both generate and compile
>   successfully
>   on my machine with 8GB heap allocated to Antlr.
>
> ...
>
> I don't believe that it will ever be possible to get a working parser in
>   Java. A C language parser on the other hand is quite possible.

Comment: I am not really sure that is entirely true. The same person 'Douglas Godfrey' posted previously on the same thread that he managed to compile it with 8GB of heap space [http://www.antlr3.org/pipermail/antlr-interest/2011-October/042850.html]. Also SQL2003 is listed on the official pages of antlr2 [http://www.antlr2.org/] and 3 as well I think (thanks to the same person). Thanks for looking into this question :)

Comment: Ruling out an entire grammar as incompatible with ANTLR is not the right way to go I think :)

Comment: @noob333 if you don't believe the words of Mr. Godfrey who used to be building SQL grammar parsers for living then I don't know who else can convince you. On the other hand a lot of great things have been built by people who didn't know it's impossible so good luck fixing that grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, basically you’re right. The grammar is broken. But also there is an error in your `ANTLRDemo.java` as there’s no `eval()` method in `Parser` class. You should call method with the name of any rule of the parser grammar e.g. `query_specification()`. In the grammar itself there were some errors looking as a typo, some undefined Java `error()` method calls, `skip()` calls in parser that are only suitable in lexer. You see all fixes in [this commit](https://github.com/lana-k/iso-sql-2003-antlr3/commit/1be6b1cd088e48fcfd0212063471404da3bdf2dc). I’ve published my research in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/lana-k/iso-sql-2003-antlr3).

I started to fix obvious errors of the grammar, which led to the compilation errors in generated java code. I had the same errors that you posted. Eventually I have fixed all Java syntax errors but faced another one which it impossible to fix directly because it originates from limitation of JVM, the `compilation error: code too large`. Reading ANTLR mailing list there was a hint to extract some static members of the huge classes into separate interfaces and “implement” them to have a sort of multiple inheritance. With trial and error I ended up with 6 interfaces ”imlemented” by parser in `sql2003Parser.java`.

But still there are 2 problems:

- **Wrong start rule.** Douglas Godfrey wrote grammar that starts with `sql2003Parser` rule. Unfortunately if you call parser by this start rule, it won’t parse correctly even simplest `select a from b`. So I call parser by `query_specification` rule to parse `SELECT` clause only.
- **Some other errors in grammar.** I didn’t dig too deep in the grammar but `query_specification` fails to parse some random complex SQLs.